# Are there Javascript frameworks designed to work well with Windows CE devices?

Tags: javascript, mobile, frameworks, windows-ce, javascript-framework

I'm trying to create a rich mobile-like interface for our [Falcon Guns](http://www.adc.datalogic.com/Falcon-X3_prd_prd145_4.html), which run Windows CE 5.0 and 6.0.

Our most recent models are the ones linked above, at 624mhz procs and 256mb ram. The older models have less.

The browser is IE that is built into the OS. I believe the version numbers match, such that CE 5.0 runs IE5* and CE 6.0 runs IE6*.

*For mobile

I've tried using dojo mobile and jquery mobile, but they render terribly and take a LOOONG time to load.

Are there any solutions that I may not be aware of? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It really depends more on the browser than the OS. I remember working with NetFront, which only had a partial implementation of JavaScript so there were many work-arounds.

Comment: It sounds like performance just plain sucks on CE/JavaScript: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/72a777a1-b693-4772-92ed-7e8b2d1311d2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slowness is due to IE and the small device hardware and not the framework you are using.
Your best bet is to go completely native and write a native c++/c application.
But if that is not an option you could look at QtWebkit on windows mobile and write your own "web browser"(very quick to write if you use the QWebView element) application and compare performance vs IE. Qt is licensed under GPL and LGPL.
Here is someone's youtube video demoing the webkit browser on WinMobile.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWhSaKyFI-Q

I believe you can use visual studio to write and debug Qt applications on the device.

If you are able to install 3rd party browsers then you should take a look at Opera mobile and skyfire.
Nevertheless you can expect a web-app to be only so fast on a mobile device.